# How to use same css for separate media query conditions

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have 2 conditions for a certain CSS rule:

```
@media all and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:1024px)
```

and

```
@media all and (max-height:900px)
```

Since I guessing I can't concatenate conditions with `or` is there a way not to duplicate the CSS rule for both conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that using a comma:

```
@media all and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:1024px), 
       all and (max-height:900px)
```